# How to launch a dialog box from a widget?

Tags: android, button, android-widget

I couldnt find anywhere a case that a widget launches a dialog box when it is clicked. Do you have any ideas?

I have this code

```
public void onUpdate(Context c, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
     for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    Intent fireDialog = new Intent(c,Execute.class);

    Toast test=Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(),"onUpdate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    test.show();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, appWidgetId, fireDialog, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Button, pendingIntent);
    Log.w(LOG_TAG,"Called");
    mgr.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
     }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate.
Is your requirement something like, click on a button and then you want a dialog to appear. ?

Comment: Can you Breifly descirbe which widget are you using and also i think you can try it in onClickListner of that widget

Comment: the requirement is click the app-widget and a dialog box should appear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming here that by "widget" you mean "app widget", the interactive elements an application can add to the user's home screen.

An app widget cannot display a `Dialog`, as that can only be done by an `Activity`. Your app widget can start up an `Activity`, though, via `startActivity()`. And, you can theme your activity to look like a dialog, by adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` to your  element.

Comment: yeah, i mean the app widget. I also update my question with the code i currently have

Comment: @JustCurious: Nothing seems too out of the ordinary with your code. Make sure your `Execute` activity has the dialog theme.

Answer (score 2):

make a activity with dialog theme, and call it

```
<activity android:name=".DailyPillDialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: When the dialog theme launch the original app is launched in the background as well. Is there a way no to launch the main app? I mean i just want the dialog box to be launched

Answer (score 0):

You can [create an AlertDialog customized](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) to your needs. Then you can `alertDialog.show()` from an `onClickListener` callback of an other widget (say Button) to show the dialog.

Comment: Is it possible to do that? @CommonsWare. I know how to create a dialog box alone. The problem is how to combine it with my app widget.